# Change an object within ArrayList using a method and return

Tags: java, arraylist, polymorphism, return

```
public class Egg extends Bee{
    protected boolean eat() {
        return true;
    }

    protected static Object anotherDay() {

        eat();
        if(age>=3)
        {
            Larvae larvae = new Larvae();
            return this;
        }
        age++;
        return this; 
    }
}


public abstract class Bee {
    protected String type;
    protected int age;
    protected int health = 3;

    protected String getType()
    {
        return type;
    }
    protected int getAge()
    {
        return age;
    }
    protected int getHealth()
    {
        return health;
    }

    protected void setAge(int age)
    {
        this.age = age;
    }

    protected abstract boolean eat();
    protected abstract static Object anotherDay();  //the bees tasks for day (should include eat())

}
```

I'm trying to change the anotherDay() method so it will return an object but I can not figure out how to do this.
that object would then replace the current one in an arrayList (an Egg object in an arrayList would turn into a Larvae object at the same point in the list)
Currently the abstract static Object is what I found to return an object but it isnt working.

Comment: I haven't seen any arraylist and seriously you need to look at your design first.

Comment: You can not `return this;` in a static context

Comment: the arrayList is in another class called hive and the not returning this from static is why im asking for another way

Comment: anotherDay() was origionally a boolean but i need to update it to return a class instead if you are wondering

Comment: @user1642671 Is there a particular reason why `anotherDay()` is static? If there is not, make it non-static.

Comment: When i looked up how to return a class from a method it told me i had to have it static is that incorrect?

Comment: @user1642671 But you are not trying to return the class, but an object of that class. In a static method, a `this` object does not exist.

Comment: sorry i ment object not class but i think i understand what static does properly now thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make the anotherDay method a void method that checks the age and if it's the right value remove the egg and add the larvae in its index.

Comment: The worksheet requires me to replace it using a return method (kind of why its  confused me or I would of done it this way but thanks)